# PHP AppEngine currently broken when using TwitterOAuth on local host

Tags: php, google-app-engine, localhost

For some reason on localhost with PHP AppEngine 1.9.24 (and verified this also occurs on 1.9.21), I get the following error due to a CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException'
```

If I comment out

```
extension = "curl.so"
```

within php.ini, and use [Purl.php](https://github.com/azayarni/purl) I get the following errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' 
with message '{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Note this code works in production. Any ideas whats going on with localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out CURLOPT_CAPATH resolved the issue.